# Java - Convert touch input to text character

Tags: java, android, text, touch

I'm attempting to make an app for Android and part of it includes the ability for me to convert an array of entries of x,y coordinates in to a character. e.g. if the coordinates form an L shape, it should return the character L.

I would assume that something like this exists already as I have seen similar things in other apps, although during my searching I wasn't able to find anything that did what I wanted (or I used the wrong search terms).

Does anyone know of any open-source systems that do this, or know of a good method for this?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Some kind of OCR package maybe?

Comment: There was a product from the Google Android folks that was targeting blind people that allowed you to draw letters on the screen.  Not sure if it was open sourced or what the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who may want to do this in the future, I ended up using Gestures by Android - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/Gesture.html and used GesturePoints to input my x,y coordinate pair.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality did exist previously (not sure if it still does, or if this project is open source) in the 'Eye's Free' product, which is designed to aid vision impaired users.

Your best bet is to use functionality from here is possible.

Source-code repo: https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/

Blog: http://eyes-free.blogspot.com/

Search for TV Raman - he is\was the lead developer for this project

I think this is the specific project you are looking for (on Eye's Free source repo): https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/downloads/detail?name=com.googlecode.eyesfree.inputmethod.latin-v1.1.6.apk&can=2&q=

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it and see if I can access the source

Comment: To be clear, this project implemented exactly what you are asking about (use gestures to draw letters on the screen).  I linked to specific source repo for the apk that does this. Think source should be there, if not, check AOSP.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Android's built-in GestureDetector (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html).  It will recognize shapes stored in a shape dictionary that you can ship with your app.  You will have to seed the dictionary (although there may be some pre-defined alphabet dictionaries for free these days, this functionality has been around since API level 1).  You can seed the dictionary by using your development environment and a utility to draw and save pre-defined shapes and map them to expected input.

The GestureDetector APIs will give you a probabilistic match between what the detector recognizes vs. what is in the dictionary and you can determine what to do with the input shape.

I have used this before in an old app and it works very well.

Here's another link to the old Android Dev docs for it: http://docs.huihoo.com/android/2.1/resources/articles/gestures.html

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't that take the gestures made by the user on the touch screen? What I'm looking for is something that takes the x,y coordinates instead of the gesture itself.

Comment: Well, no particular sense in recreating the wheel but the `MotionEvent` caught in the gesture listener has access to raw and historical X/Y coordinates if needed.

Comment: Sorry for such a delayed reply. I've been looking and can't find any gesture dictionaries with alphabet characters in them or anything similar to that. Are there any that you know of?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's anything pre-packaged, but you can use a locally-installed app to "train" an alphabet library (stored as a file), and the library can be installed as a resource within your application.  http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html is an old link by Romain Guy (the images are dead) but the key is the GestureLibrary which he explains briefly.  The huihoo.com link I posted above still includes the old resources (the libraries are still valid in Android 4 even if they reference old 1.6).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the Gesture class and used the GesturePoints class to input the x,y pair. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: By the way, I'm happy to accept this answer and delete mine if it helps you and you're able to edit your answer to include the GesturePoint information.
Really don't want to upset anyone, I just want the best answer for people who see this in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I was in the wrong. I was having a bad day when I wrote that, don't mean it personally.  If you edit your answer (move a punctuation mark, something simple) I can re-upvote it.

Comment: Done. No worries, I do get where you're coming from, and maybe I should have let you know about the change instead of making my own answer.